# Restrict 3D plot to region specified by an inequality

Tags: graphics3d, inequalities

I would liked to plot a piece of the unit sphere surface within the region defined by

$$x \geq y \geq z \geq 0$$

Plotting the region (`RegionPlot3D`) and the sphere (`Graphics3D`) is no problem, but I would like to restrict the plot domain to the area specified by the inequality, i.e. I want the intersection between the volume and the sphere surface. Is that possible?

Comment: `RegionPlot3D[
 0 < z <= y <= x && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0,
   1}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None]`?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: @kglr That'll do it for the moment, thanks. Any way to plot the surface only?

Comment: @José Antonio Díaz Navas As I said, plotting the region and my sphere's surface independently is not the problem, I'm just looking for a built-in method to restrict any existing plot to any arbitrary region, when these two items can be plotted separately. There's not much I can try but to inquire about features unknown to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `region = 0 <= z <= y <= x` you can use

```
RegionPlot3D[region && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, 
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None]
```

[image]

> ***Any way to plot the surface only?***

You can use `ParametricPlot3D` or `ContourPlot3D` to get the surface of a sphere:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[v] Sin[u], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None,      MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 100,
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, region]]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, region], 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ParametricPlot3D[ConditionalExpression[{Cos[v] Sin[u], Sin[v] Sin[u], Cos[u]}, 
  0 < Cos[u] <= Sin[v] Sin[u] <= Cos[v] Sin[u]], 
 {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None,  MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: `RegionFunction`, that's it! Thank you.

Comment: @kglr no need to use `ParametricPlot3D` to get the surface, just `ContourPlot3D` don't you?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas, you are right; just added that alternative.